# Receiving 'useState', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type although type specified

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am receiving a Typescript error 'useState', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type error although I have specified the type specifically, based on the best examples I can find.  The applicable lines of my code are as follows:

```
    interface IBDMRecord {
                           businessDevelopmentResourceId: number;
                           referenceName: string;
                         }

    class ManagePreSalesBDMsApp extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {

        static defaultProps: IAppProps = {
            baseUrl: (window as any).SERVER_BASE_URL,
            systemVersion: (window as any).SYSTEM_VERSION
        }    

        const [data, setData] = useState<IBDMRecord[]>([]);
```

Visual Studio Code shows this as the problem:

[image: Message from Visual Studio Code]

Typescript v4.4.4 is installed.  React v17.0.2 is installed.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Update:  I refactored to lambda function syntax and all is well.

Comment: You cannot use hooks inside class component, according to the React documentation

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, Georgy.  I guess I am glad that Typescript is throwing the fit, although I can't quite fathom how it knows that to be the problem.